# MySQL - joining the same table 4 times having column 2,3 & 4 random and all different

Tags: mysql, random

for simplicity lets say it has only 1 field.  ID.

In MySQL, i want to list all the IDs just once (and in order) in the first column of the result, but in 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns i want to display random IDs from the same table - all 4 IDs need to be different in each row.

I'll explain visually. eg table with 5 rows:

ID:

A

B

C

D

E

RESULT should look something like this:

A  B  D  C

B  C  E  D

C  A  D  B

D  E  C  B

E  A  C  B

I'm very new to MySQL - although have plenty experience with other SQLs. I've tried to use RAND() and LIMIT and i get incorrect results - either column 1 has duplicates or columns 2,3 & 4 returned only one result all the way down.

help - please

=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MichaelRushton's method can optimize to
SELECT id1, id2, id3, id4 FROM (
SELECT t1.id id1, t2.id id2, t3.id id3, t4.id id4
FROM tt t1
    INNER JOIN tt t2 ON t2.id !=t1.id
    INNER JOIN tt t3 ON t3.id !=t1.id AND t3.id !=t2.id
    INNER JOIN tt t4 ON t4.id !=t1.id AND t4.id !=t2.id AND t4.id !=t3.id
ORDER BY RAND()) AS t
GROUP BY t.id1
ORDER BY NULL;

other method:
SELECT (@a:=`id`) AS a
 ,(@b:=(SELECT `id` FROM `tt` WHERE id NOT IN (@a) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)) AS b
 ,(@c:=(SELECT `id` FROM `tt` WHERE id NOT IN (@a,@b) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)) AS c
 ,(@d:=(SELECT `id` FROM `tt` WHERE id NOT IN (@a,@b,@c) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)) AS d
FROM `tt` AS t,(SELECT @a,@b,@c,@d) AS t2
ORDER BY t.id;

or

SELECT a, b, c,(SELECT `id` FROM `tt` AS td WHERE id NOT IN (a,b,c) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS d 
FROM (SELECT a, b,(SELECT `id` FROM `tt` AS tc WHERE id NOT IN (a,b) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS c 
    FROM (SELECT a,(SELECT `id` FROM `tt` AS tb WHERE id NOT IN (a) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS b 
        FROM (SELECT `id` AS a FROM `tt` AS ta) AS tt1
         ) AS tt2
      ) AS tt3
 ORDER BY a;

but its efficiency is very low!
```

Comment: Thanks both for this very quick and helpful reply - i tested the first one above and it is returning just what i am after. I only want to fetch this data once and stick it into an array, so hopefully if it isn't too efficient, it won;t matter too much.

Comment: Just so you know ... i was using the first one above on my table of 89 rows and it worked ok if i only used 3 columns, but took forever if i used all 4. the id field is indexed/primary key. Anyway i have just tried the last one - with very low efficiency and it returned all 4 columns at lightening speed. this is great news =)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT
    t1.id id1,
    t2.id id2,
    t3.id id3,
    t4.id id4
FROM
    test t1, test t2, test t3, test t4
WHERE
    t1.id NOT IN (t2.id, t3.id, t4.id)
    AND
    t2.id NOT IN (t3.id, t4.id)
    AND
    t3.id != t4.id
GROUP BY
    t1.id
ORDER BY
    RAND()
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9adc/5

Comment: Thankyou - that was quick!  i tweaked it to my actual table but it gave me only the first non matching fields it could find.   so for example i got:

A  B  C  D

B  A  C  D

C  A  B  D

D  A  B  C

E  A  B  C


i have about 200 rows and would like it to result in a more random 2, 3 & 4 field

Comment: Do you mean it only returned the first row or only the first column? If the latter, it could be because I hadn't aliased the selected column names; I've added them now.

Comment: sorry i'm having trouble formatting my result into something readable ?!

Comment: Are you sure you copied by code exactly? As you can see from the fiddle, it works.

Comment: i've just had a look at the fiddle - i guess i should have made more rows to give you an idea of what i mean. if the table has 10 rows - say from A to J you will be able to see more clearly that it only tends to bring back the first 3 available rows for columns 2,3 and 4

Comment: i added a few more rows to the table and it displays it better. i need  columns 2,3 and 4 to display a bigger range - probably needs more RAND() in there somewhere

Comment: This shows the problem i still have - i would like to see more random numbers between 5 and 10 showing also.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b936/2   any ideas how we can randomise the last 3 columns a little more?